# Extract Top Level Domain from Domain name

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of top level domains like:

```
['ag', 'asia', 'asia_sunrise', 'com', 'com.ag', 'org.hn']
```

Given a domain name, how can i extract the top level domain of the domain name based on the array above? Basically i dont care of how many levels the domain has, i only need to extract the top level domain.

For example:

test1.ag -> should return ag

test2.com.ag -> should return com.ag

test.test2.com.ag -> should return com.ag

test3.org -> should return false

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need regex? I'd use [strrpos()](http://php.net/strrpos) to find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to incorporate *Traxo's* point about the `.` wildcard; I think my answer is a little fuller so I'll leave it up but we've both essentially come to the same solution.

```
//set up test variables
$aTLDList = ['ag', 'asia', 'asia_sunrise', 'com', 'com.ag', 'org.hn'];
$sDomain = "badgers.co.uk"; // for example

//build the match
$reMatch = '/^.*?\.(' . str_replace('.', '\.', implode('|', $aTLDList)) . ')$/';
$sMatchedTLD = preg_match($reMatch, $sDomain) ? 
        preg_replace($reMatch, "$1", $sDomain) : 
        "";
```

Resorting to Regular Expressions *may* be overkill but it makes for a concise example. This will give you either the TLD matched **or** an empty string in the `$sMatchedTLD` variable.

The trick is to make the first `.*` match *ungreedy* (`.*?`) otherwise **badgers.com.ag** will match **ag** rather than **com.ag**.

Comment: Your solution gives my exactly what i want, a string. Traxo kinda does, but not exactly what i want. If he updates his answer to fully satisfy my needs i accept is, otherwise i will acept your answer. Big Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$domains = ['ag', 'asia', 'asia_sunrise', 'com', 'com.ag', 'org.hn'];

$str = 'test.test2.com.ag'; //your string

preg_match('/\b('.str_replace('.', '\.', implode('|', $domains)).')$/', $str, $matches);
//replace . with \. because . is reserved in regex for any character 

$result = $matches[0] ?: false;
```

Edit: added word boundary in regexp and $result is your string or false

Comment: Traxo you answer dont fully does what i asked. But because you point out the possible solution, if you update your answer i will acept it otherwise i will accept CD0001. Please read my comment on CD0001. Big Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[parseurl()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function gives you access to the host name of the url. You can use that to process the host name and find out the tld.

```
$url = 'http://your.url.com.np';
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Next steps could be using explode() to split the host name and checking the last item in the exploded list. But I am going to leave that to you.

Comment: I dont have a url, so i dont need to parse it. I know i can explode, but a top level domain can be for example "com.ag", so even if i acess the last item in the exploded array they dont always match.

Comment: On that case I would suggest to have list of all the gtlds and tld and match against them.

Answer (score 0):

using regexp is not realy needed, so should be avoided here.

```
  function topDomain($url) {
      $arr = ['ag', 'asia', 'asia_sunrise', 'com', 'hn'];

      $tld = parse_url($url);
      $toplevel = explode(".", $tld['path'] );
      if(in_array(end($toplevel),$arr)){
         return $url;
      }
```

ps. 'com.ag' and 'org.hn' are not toplevel domains, but second level domains, so these were left out in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should provide an array sorted by length of similar domains, for example 'com.ag' before 'ag'. And then:

```
function get_domain($s){
    $a = ['com.ag', 'ag', 'asia_sunrise', 'asia', 'com', 'org.hn'];
    foreach($a as $v){
        if(preg_match("/$v$/",$s)){// if it ends with the array's value
            return $v;
        }
    }
    return false;// if none matched the pattern, loop ends and returns false
}
echo get_domain('test.test2.com.ag');// com.ag
```